# Why are my Notes not be displayed as I want?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to display my own Notes which I create but the problem is it doesn´t be displayed on the page. I have built in console.log () modules, but unfortunately I do not know what it is hacking, that they are undefined. I see the Notes in my state.

My Redux function to request the Notes by me (It works in my Backend)

```
export const listForumUser = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
          type: NOTES_LIST_REQUEST,
        });
    
        const {
          userLogin: { userInfo },
        } = getState();
    
        const config = {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token.token}`,
          },
        };

       
        const url = "http://localhost:8080/forum/getByToken";
        
        const {data}= await axios.get(url, config);

    
        dispatch({
          type: NOTES_LIST_SUCCESS,
          payload: data,
        });
      
      } catch (error) {
        const message =
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message;
        dispatch({
          type: NOTES_LIST_FAIL,
          payload: message,
        });
      }
};
```

My Frontend page :

```
function NotesMe ({ history,search }){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
    const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
    const { userInfo } = userLogin;

    const noteList = useSelector(state => state.noteList);
    const { forum } = noteList;


    const deleteHandler = (_id) => {
      if (window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        dispatch(deleteNoteAction(_id));
      }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(listForumUser());
    } , [dispatch]); 
  return (
    
    <MainScreen title={` ${userInfo.auth.username}´s Forum..`}>
      {console.log(forum)}
   

    <Link to="createForum">
      <Button style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 6 }} size="lg">
        Create New Forum
      </Button>
    </Link>
  
      {forum &&
        forum.map((forum) => (
          <Accordion>
              <Card style={{ margin: 10 }} key={forum._id}>
          <Card.Header style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <span
                    // onClick={() => ModelShow(note)}
                    style={{
                      color: "black",
                      textDecoration: "none",
                      flex: 1,
                      cursor: "pointer",
                      alignSelf: "center",
                      fontSize: 18,
                    }}
                  >
                       

                      {forum.forumName}
                     
                
                  </span>
            

            <div>
              <Button to='notesEdit'>Edit</Button>
              <Button
                variant="danger"
                className="mx-2"
                onClick={() => deleteHandler(forum._id)}
              >
                Delete
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Card.Header>
          
          <Card.Body>
            
            <blockquote className="blockquote mb-0">
              <ReactMarkdown>{forum.forumDescription}</ReactMarkdown>
              <footer className="blockquote-footer">
              Created on{" "}
                        <cite title="Source Title">
                          {forum.published_on.substring(0, 300)}
                          {forum.user}
                          
                        </cite>
              </footer>
            </blockquote>
          </Card.Body>
          
        </Card>
          </Accordion>
        
       
      ))}
    </MainScreen>
    
  );
  



};

export default NotesMe;
```

The Backend Response:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61b892bc83af6eecd758346a",
    "forumName": "My first Note",
    "forumDescription": "My first Note Description.",
    "published_on": "December 14, 2021 1:47 PM",
    "user": "61b38cac5161c67e334907bc",
    "__v": 0
  },
]
```

Reducer:

```
export const noteListReducer = (state = { notes: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case NOTES_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true };
        case NOTES_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, notes: action.payload };
        case NOTES_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
        
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

State:

```
NoteList: 
  loading: false
 notes:
   -> 0 : _id: ... and so on..
```

I hope someone sees the error and can fix it easily ...